# Spring Rest Template to send JsonArray

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am using spring rest template to send json array as request. Source code to send request is as follow:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

for (Iterator iterator = itemlist.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

    Item item = (Item)iterator.next();

    JSONObject formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();

    formDetailsJson.put("id", item.getItemConfId());
    formDetailsJson.put("name", item.getItems().getItemName());
    formDetailsJson.put("price", item.getPrice());
    formDetailsJson.put("Cost",item.getCost());

    jsonArray.put(formDetailsJson);
}


List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

// Prepare header
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
// Pass the new person and header
HttpEntity<JSONArray> entity = new HttpEntity<JSONArray>(jsonArray, headers);

System.out.println("Json Object : "+entity);
// Send the request as POST
try {
    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange("my url", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(e);

    return "Connection not avilable please try again";
}
```

And to accept request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testStock", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
    public @ResponseBody int testStock(@RequestBody List<ItemList>  jsonArray) {

        logger.debug("Received request to connect ms access : "+jsonArray.size());

        //int returnSizecount = stockList.getStocklst().size();

        return 1;
    }
```

The problem is that it giving me following error:
 Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.json.JSONArray].Any suggestion is greatly acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no MessageConverter for JSONArray, so I suggest do the following.

```
HttpEntity<JSONArray> entity = new HttpEntity<JSONArray>(jsonArray, headers);
```

Convert Class JSONArray to String, and add that to HttpEntity, you know use toString

> java.lang.String  toString()
>
> ```
>       Make a JSON text of this JSONArray.
> ```

HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(jsonArray.toString(), headers);

Or change to Jackson implementation Spring have support to that. XD

If you dont want to do the above, consider create your own implementation of messageConverter, that will work but is harder

**update**

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

**update 2** Change endpoint to.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testStock", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody int testStock(@RequestBody String  jsonArray) {
```

Comment: Convert it to tostring(). For request acceptance it is giving me 415 unsupported media type at server side.

Comment: Add a header like this : header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), this telll the server that the String is a json, please let me know if that works

Comment: I had already add it as media type in my code. What to do on server side means at testStock method in my code.

Comment: update in my answer, try that if works then tweak it

Comment: Thanks to your comment, I understood there would be no converter for the JSONObject either. So I converted the JSONObject to a string as in: HttpEntity<String> entityCredentials = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonCredentials.toString(), httpHeaders); and it now works just fine. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

you need to have httpmessageconverter  configured for your resttemplate, please read my post for configuring  http message conveter for you webservice

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963127/new-to-spring-and-jackson-2-what-does-this-bean-declaration-allow-for-in-a-spri/19973636#19973636.
```

and for you problem to convert your http request to json you might add this entry in your restemplate configuration

```
 <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
```

Comment: I think jsonarray can not be converted for that MessageConverter, because JsonArray does not belongs to Jackson libs

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite straightforward. You do not have a converter for the JSONArray. Converting the array to a String (using toString) did help you here, but there is a better way:

Just add a converter for the json.org objects:

Add this to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And then on your ObjectMapper add the JsonOrgModule:

```
mapper.registerModule(new JsonOrgModule());
```